# Living with roommate not on the lease

Tags: residential-lease, breaking-the-lease

Suppose someone enters into an apartment lease which specifically forbids guests for staying for extended periods of time. The leasee then violates the contract by hosting a guest for an extended period of time. The issue may surface after the lease ends when the guest is questioned about previous locations they have lived in a number of circumstances (applying for jobs, their own apartment, etc).

Are there possible legal repercussions for either party (leasee, guest) for violation of this policy after the lease has ended?

Update: the state is Illinois.

Update: this is also considering the case in which the tenant pays their own utilities.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The landlord might be able to sue the tenant for actual damages arising from the double occupancy, if utilities are paid by the landlord. Two people tend to use more water than one person. Establishing that there has been any loss would be tricky, but let's assume that there is evidence pointing to some dollar figure. Then the landlord might sue the tenant for causing this damage.